# "'Symbol' object does not support indexing" error

Tags: python, sympy

I have a function:

```
def s(x):
    t = lambda a: a*sp.sin(3.0/a)
    return t(x)
```

that I am trying to integrate from 0 to 2. When the function `s(x)` is in the same file as the operations I am performing on it, I get the correct answer. For example, when I have the file:

```
def s(x):
    t = lambda a: a*sp.sin(3.0/a)
    return t(x)

x = sp.Symbol('x')

d_s = lambda a: sp.integrate(s(x), x)
print((d_s(x).subs(x,2) - sp.limit(d_s(x), x, 0)).evalf(25))
```

I get the correct value, which is `1.099` and some change. However, when I don't have them all in the same file I get the `'Symbol' object does not support indexing` error. Here's the code causing the problem:

```
import HW8
# Finding exact values of integrals
x = sp.Symbol('x')
p_exact = sp.integrate(HW8.p(x), (x, 0, 2)).evalf(25)
q_exact = sp.integrate(HW8.q(x), (x, 0, 2)).evalf(25)

# Have to do something special for s(x) due to the discontinuity at x = 0
s_int = lambda x: sp.integrate(HW8.s(x), x)
s_exact = (s_int(x).sub(x,2) - sp.limit(s_int(x), x, 0)).evalf(25)
print(s_exact)
```

Here is the HW8 code containing the functions:

```
import sympy as sp

def p(x):
    result = 0.5 + x * (2.0 - x)
    return result

def q(x):
    result = 2.0 + x * (-8.0 + x * (14.0 + x * (-7.0 + x)))
    return result

def s(x):
    t = lambda a: a*sp.sin(3.0/a)
    return t(x)
```

Here is a traceback:

```
s(x)
     12     t = lambda a: a*sp.sin(3.0/a)
     13     return t(x)

TypeError: 'Symbol' object does not support indexing 

<lambda>(x)
     11 
     12 # Have to do something special for s(x) due to the discontinuity at x = 0
---> 13 s_int = lambda x: sp.integrate(HW8.s(x), x)
     14 s_exact = (s_int(x).sub(x,2) - sp.limit(s_int(x), x, 0)).evalf(25)
     15 print(s_exact)

<module>()
     12 # Have to do something special for s(x) due to the discontinuity at x = 0
     13 s_int = lambda x: sp.integrate(HW8.s(x), x)
---> 14 s_exact = (s_int(x).sub(x,2) - sp.limit(s_int(x), x, 0)).evalf(25)
     15 print(s_exact)
     16 

execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    195             else:
    196                 filename = fname
--> 197             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    198     else:
    199         def execfile(fname, *where):
```

I've tested this code without `s(x)` implemented, and it gives me no errors and performs flawlessly.

Could I get some insights into *why* this might be happening?

Comment: Do you have any wildcard imports (`from foo import *`) that could import a different `s`?

Comment: The only other imports I am using are `import pylab as pl`, `import sympy as sp`, `import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl`, and `from simp_trap import *` which only has two functions titled `simpson(f,a,b,n)` and `trapezoid(f,a,b,n)`.

Comment: i ran the code you provided and it returned me correctly "1.099693997908721856194448"

Comment: @adrianX Was `s(x)` and the operations you performed on it in the same file?

Comment: Why the indirection in the definition of `s(x)`? Why not just have `return x*sp.sin(3.0/x)`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere in your code that would cause this. The error message would come from using the square bracket syntax on a Symbol, like `x[1]` where `x = Symbol('x')`.